# Как считать из файла только цифры?

Tags: c++, fstream

Пример кода:

```
#inclde<fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream in("input.txt");

int main()
{
    int templateINT;
    char templateCHAR;
    in >> something from this;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Поясните понятнее, что вам нужно...

Comment: Что делает этот пример кода?

Comment: Хочет считывать из input.txt 
[adsfddggd 75] только цифры

Comment: Пример входных данных: 19:20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int k = 0;
while(true) {
if (!isdigit(char (in.peek())))
        in.ignore();
    else  {
        in >> k;
        cout << k << ' ';
    }
}
```

Можете не выводить, а хранить цифры в контейнере

Answer (score 0):

```
void process(const std::string& str, std::vector<int>& numbers) {
    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
        if (isdigit(str[i])) numbers.push_back(int(str[i]) - 48);
}

string line;
std::vector<int> numbers;
ifstream f ("file");
if (!f.is_open()) {
    perror("error while opening file");
    return -1;
}
while(getline(f, line))
    process(&line, numbers);
```